# How do I bypass the "harmful file" download warning on chrome with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python/selenium to download multiple config files from a few hundred IP devices. How can I bypass this warning and download these files automatically?

["This type of file may be harmful to your computer" Keep/Discard"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkEnn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome_options to change the default download settings for Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {}
prefs["download.prompt_for_download"] = False
prefs["download.directory_upgrade"] = True
prefs["default_content_setting_values.notifications"] = 0
prefs["content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting"] = 1
prefs["safebrowsing.disable_download_protection"] = True
prefs["default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["managed_default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["profile.password_manager_enabled"] = False
prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications"] = 2
prefs["profile.default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads"] = 1
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Or you can use a Selenium Python framework that already has these settings by default: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just adding chrome profile..... I don't why, but it works...